# Autocomplete commands for custom functions defined in .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a `.bash_profile` file with many functions.
e.g.

```bash
function open() {
    blah blah;
}

function open-remote() {
    blah blah blah;
}

function open-local() {
    duh;
}

function operation() {
    duh duh;
}
```

Now, when I type `op` and `tab` it should list down all the functions that are available from this prefix. I don't care about autocompletion of sub-commands for each of te commands.

All the guides I saw are about auto-completion of subcommands which I am not looking for.

Any way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want it *not* to include other commands that begin with `op` or something? Because otherwise, as far as I know, this is default behavior.

Comment: As @frabjous said, that should be the default behavior. Are you sure that `.bash_profile` is being read by bash? If the configurations for login shells don't define the `.bash_profile` as a sourced file then your code inside that file won't have effect.

Comment: Try to execute those functions in a new shell, and if you get error, then, the file is not sourced. Or you can try using the file `.bashrc` instead  of `.bash_profile`. In my case the configuration for login shells for home directories source the content of `.bashrc`

Comment: The file is definitely sourced and I can execute the functions just fine when I type them out, and autocomplete just doesn’t work.

Comment: @Pratik do you have installed the `bash-autocompletion`? The file might be located into **/usr/share/bash-completion**